# PHP session.save_path ignored

Tags: php, apache, session

I was having problems with my PHP website (SuiteCRM) not being able to log users in and I found it was due to not being able to write on the sessions directory.

I am able to fix it by creating the directory `/tmp/php_sessions` and giving it write permissions for the Apache user `www-data`. I see the directory get populated with files as users log in.

However, Ubuntu Xenial is deleting my entire `tmp` directory on reboots, so I have to redo this all over again every time. I decided to move my `save_path` elsewhere.

After changing things in my php.ini file, and restarting Apache, I can check that they are effective by running this simple script:

```
<?php
   echo ini_get("session.save_path");

   phpinfo();
?>
```

This shows me a double confirmation of the new path, first echoing `/var/tmp/php_sessions` and then, in the middle of all the phpinfo information, showing the same value as both `Local Value` and `Master value` for directive `session.save_path`.

**BUT** the directory that php is using is still the first one, `/tmp/php_sessions`! It seems that my setting is being ignored.

Am I overlooking something? Where could that old setting be buried? Or how can I make the new one effective?

(P.S. - I am not using a `redis` handler as in another similar SO question)

Comment: Do you have permission to edit your `php.ini` file?

Comment: Did you have manually set the session path

Comment: Try to add the session path manually using this code `ini_set(session.save_path, '/path/to/your/folder')` , place this code after `<?php` , after that you start your session using `session_start()`

Comment: @VigneshChinnaiyan I tried it and it didn't work, same results. However, your comment put me on the right track and I was able to solve the problem. I'll be posting it as an answer in a few minutes. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved my own problem and the **general answer** is as follows:

There are two more things that can be changing the path and need to be checked,

1. the PHP code of the application might be changing the `ini` directive, search the code for `ini_set(session.save_path`
2. the PHP code might be using the `session_save_path` PHP command to override the `ini`. Search the code for that also (and notice the two underscores `_`!)

And the **specific answer** for my case was that SuiteCRM uses `session_save_path` command to set its path with a value coming from the file `config.php` found at the web root. That's where I found the old setting, and changing it solved my problem (for good, I hope).